# EAR integration test with arquillian

Tags: java, glassfish, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian, payara

I have the following real project structure:

```
EAR
 - lib/commons.jar
 - lib/another dependencies
 - ejb.jar
```

I want to test it with arquillian but I always get an exception.

This is my java method where the EAR is built:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {
    //create ear
    EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap
            .create(EnterpriseArchive.class, "test-app.ear");

    // create ejb-jar
    JavaArchive ejb = ShrinkWrap
            .create(JavaArchive.class, "test-ejb.jar")
            .addPackage("a.b.ejb")
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

    // resolve ejb dependencies
    File[] dependencies = Maven.resolver()
            .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
            .importDependencies(ScopeType.COMPILE, ScopeType.TEST)
            .resolve()
            .withTransitivity()
            .asFile();

    ear.addAsModule(ejb);
    ear.addAsLibraries(dependencies);
    ear.setApplicationXML("glassfish-resources.xml");

    LOGGER.debug("content: " + ear.toString(true));
    return ear;
}
```

The content looks fine but something is not okay because I get this exception:

```
ArquillianServletRunner not found.
Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer.
```

**JAR content:**

```
/a/
/a/b/
/a/b/ejb/
/a/b/ejb/MyEjb.class
...
/META-INF/
/META-INF/beans.xml
```

**EAR content**

```
/test-ejb.jar
/lib/
/lib/commons-444750341265461918.jar
/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar
/lib/guava-21.0.jar
...
/lib/arquillian-testenricher-initialcontext-1.1.13.Final.jar
/lib/payara-embedded-all-4.1.1.171.0.1.jar
/lib/postgresql-42.0.0.jar
/META-INF/
/META-INF/application.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why I got "`ArquillianServletRunner not found`" error was because there was an error on EJB level.

**The following test code works properly:**

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class EchoServiceBeanTest {

    @EJB
    private EchoService echoService;

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        // create ear
        EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap
                .create(EnterpriseArchive.class, "test-app.ear");

        // create ejb.jar
        JavaArchive ejb = ShrinkWrap
                .create(JavaArchive.class, "test-ejb.jar")
                .addPackages(true, "a.b.ejb")
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        LOGGER.debug("EJB content: " + ejb.toString(true));

        // build ear
        ear.addAsModule(ejb);

        LOGGER.debug("EAR deployment content: " + ear.toString(true));
        return ear;
    }

    @Test
    public void echo() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNotNull(echoService);
        String expected = "hello";
        String returned = echoService.echo(expected);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, returned);
    }
}
```

used maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- provided jars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- arquillian -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- embedded EE container -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>payara-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.171.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```